# terraform aws: Incorrect protocol in creating a security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the following `aws_security_group` I would like to implement with terraform:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "ort_to_db" {
  name   = "MySQL/AURORA"
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.vpc_ort.id
 

  ingress {
    from_port   = 3306
    to_port     = 3306
    protocol    = "MYSQL/Aurora"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = -1
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

However, I'm receiving the following error on `terraform apply`:

> Error: updating Security Group ingress rules:
> authorizing Security Group (ingress) rules: InvalidParameterValue:
> Invalid value 'mysql/aurora' for IP protocol. Unknown protocol. │
> status code: 400, request id: d0

I've been checking from the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group_rule#protocol) all the potential values as `protocol`.
However it looks like it's not in the [extended documentation](https://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml)

Is there any workaround or should I forget at the moment to use the specific protocol proposed by AWS?
[image: Protocol proposed by AMAZON in its UI]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong field, the protocol type is `TCP`, and you were looking at the `Type` field. You can see in the screenshot it is greyed out and says TCP. The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/security-group-rules-reference.html#sg-rules-db-server) says that as well. So you need to fix this:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "ort_to_db" {
  name   = "MySQL/AURORA"
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.vpc_ort.id
 

  ingress {
    from_port   = 3306
    to_port     = 3306
    protocol    = "TCP"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = -1
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

In the docs, look at the `Protocol type` column.

[image]

---

Comment: Thanks @marko-e! That was an easy one ^^

Answer (score 1):

I think aws_security_group accept only the basic protocols Like TCP or UDP...
If you are using MySQL just use TCP because that's what MySQL use.